# PHP turn flat array into multidimensional relational array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recursive function to generate multidimensional array from database result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587341/recursive-function-to-generate-multidimensional-array-from-database-result)

Consider the following array.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Parent_ID] => 0
            [Child_ID] => 0
            [0] => string:val

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Parent_ID] => 0
            [Child_ID] => 1
            [0] => string:val

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Parent_ID] => 1
            [Child_ID] => 2
            [0] => string:val

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Parent_ID] => 0
            [Child_ID] => 3
            [0] => string:val

        )
```

I need to get this into something like the following.

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Parent_ID] => 0
            [Child_ID] => 0
            [0] => string:val

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Parent_ID] => 0
            [Child_ID] => 1
            [0] => string:val


                [2] => Array
                   (
                    [Parent_ID] => 1
                    [Child_ID] => 2
                    [0] => string:val

                    ) 
                   )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Parent_ID] => 0
            [Child_ID] => 3
            [0] => string:val

        )
```

Further to that, Children can also have unlimited children. And not every index will have the same amount of keys and values. But all will have a parent and child key/value.

Iv'e tried numerous solutions from here and elsewhere and just cant seem to get it right.

Comment: Whats the logic on witch key to convert to sub array?

Comment: if Parent_ID matches an array, Place the matched array in its parent.