# Make hierarchical array for json treemaker js data from database query result array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to fill data json for treemaker.js from database data; the result set looks like this:

```
[
    ['id' => 1, 'root' => 1, 'parent_id' => 0],
    ['id' => 2, 'root' => 1, 'parent_id' => 1],
    ['id' => 3, 'root' => 1, 'parent_id' => 2],
    ['id' => 4, 'root' => 1, 'parent_id' => 2],
    ['id' => 5, 'root' => 1, 'parent_id' => 3],
    ['id' => 6, 'root' => 1, 'parent_id' => 3],
    ['id' => 7, 'root' => 1, 'parent_id' => 4],
    ['id' => 8, 'root' => 1, 'parent_id' => 4],
    ['id' => 9, 'root' => 1, 'parent_id' => 4],
]
```

I expected the json output should be like this:

```
{ 
    '1': {
        '2': {
            '3': {
                '5': '',
                '6': '',
            },
            '4': {
                '7': '',
                '8': '',
                '9': '',
            },
        },
    },
}
```

I already tried :

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = [];
    $new = [];
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $children = $this->buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element[$element['id']] = $children;
            } else {
                $element[$element['id']] = '';
            }
            unset($element["id"]);
            unset($element["root"]);
            unset($element["parent_id"]);
            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}

public function test($id)
{
    $data = $this->Data_model->getDataByRoot($id)->result_array();
    $tree = $this->buildTree($data);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( json_encode($tree, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
}
```

I got the reference from [PHP hierarchical array - Parents and childs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877656/php-hierarchical-array-parents-and-childs), but the result is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx7hZ.png).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
function buildTree(array &$elements, $parentId = 0)
{
    $branch = [];

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $id = $element['id'];
            $children = buildTree($elements, $id);

            if ($children) {
                $branch[$id] = $children;
            } else {
                $branch[$id] = '';
            }
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

While iterating and recursing when a matching `parent_id` is encountered, push the child data into an element which is keyed by the current row's `id`.  If there are no children for the row, fall back to an empty string with the shorthand ternary operator (aka "Elvis operator").

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ofP5r))

```
function buildTree(array $rows, int $parentId = 0): array {
    $new = [];
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if ($row['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $new[$row['id']] = buildTree($rows, $row['id']) ?: '';
        }
    }
    return $new;
}

$resultSet = [
    ['id' => 1, 'parent_id' => 0],
    ['id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 1],
    ['id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 2],
    ['id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 2],
    ['id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 3],
    ['id' => 6, 'parent_id' => 3],
    ['id' => 7, 'parent_id' => 4],
    ['id' => 8, 'parent_id' => 4],
    ['id' => 9, 'parent_id' => 4],
];

var_export(
    buildTree($resultSet)
);
```

My advice largely resembles the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29384894/2943403).