# Get directory path from direcory array tree in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, path, directory

I have troubles with this task. Im new in PHP.
I think i must user recursive funcruion, but i do not understand how it use

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent_id] => 0
            [name] => New Folder
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [id] => 2
            [parent_id] => 1
            [name] => New Folder2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parent_id] => 2
            [name] => New Folder3
        )
    ......
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [parent_id] => 0
            [name] => New Folder6
        )
    [6] => Array (
            [id] => 7
            [parent_id] => 6
            [name] => New Folder7
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [parent_id] => 6
            [name] => New Folder8
        )
)
```

I need to build direcory's path like this:

```
/New Folder
/New Folder/New Folder2
/New Folder/New Folder2/New Folder3
...
/New Folder6
/New Folder6/New Folder7
/New Folder6/New Folder8
```

Can you help me whith this task?
Thx.

Comment: Start with some [generic tree building](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587341/recursive-function-to-generate-multidimensional-array-from-database-result) to build a multidimensional array representing the tree. With your newly won skills in recursive functions, traverse that tree and build the paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$txtTree[0]="/";

foreach($treeArray as $branch){

    if(isset($txtTree[$branch['parent_id']])) {
        $txtTree[$branch['id']] = $txtTree[$branch['parent_id']] . $branch['name']. "/";
    }
} 

print_r($txtTree);


Array
(
    [0] => /
    [1] => /New Folder/
    [2] => /New Folder/New Folder2/
    [3] => /New Folder/New Folder2/New Folder3/
    [6] => /New Folder6/
    [7] => /New Folder6/New Folder7/
    [8] => /New Folder6/New Folder8/
)
```