# How to generate breadcrumbs using recursion on database row data?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, breadcrumbs

I have to make a breadcrumb menu which comes database.

So made this function

```
function file_list($path) {
    $result = array();
    $q = "SELECT staticTitle,staticId,parentId FROM tbl_static_pages WHERE staticId = $path";
    $run = mysql_query($q);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run)) {
        if($row['parentId'] > 1) {
            echo $row['staticTitle'];
            $result = file_list($row['parentId']);
            return $result; // INSERTED
        }else { 
            return $result; 
        }  
    }
```

I have a database structure like this:

```
 id | parentId | title
 3  |  1      | keyword
 28 |  3      | xxx
 31 | 28      | business
```

I want to output like this `business -> xxx -> keyword`

I want to run this function until `$row['parentId'] = 1`.
When I echo the title, I got correct result.
When I try it to store it in array, I always get single value.

How can I return an array in recursive array?

Comment: check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587341/recursive-function-to-generate-multidimensional-array-from-database-result

Comment: Recursion + SQL == Mayhem.

Answer (score 1):

I REALLY don't like the idea of recursive calls on the database.  If this is a "breadcrumbs" database table, how big could it possibly be?  ...I mean size is probably not a concern.

I would like to suggest that you pull the full table out (3 columns, all rows) and assign the resultset to a php variable.  This means you only ever make one trip to the database -- and that's a good thing.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bb54c153925eb5c808ddefe4b0fb1a1f2f9af9d0))

```
function breadcrumber($array,$id){
    static $result=[];  // declare the storage variable without losing elements during recursion
    if(isset($array[$id])){  // if target exists
        $result[]=$array[$id]['title'];  // store title text
        $parent=$array[$id]['parentId'];  // assign new target
        unset($array[$id]);  // remove possibility of an infinite loop
        breadcrumber($array,$parent);  // recurse
    }
    return $result;
}

$resultset=[
    ['id'=>3,'parentId'=>1,'title'=>'keyword'],
    ['id'=>28,'parentId'=>3,'title'=>'xxx'],
    ['id'=>31,'parentId'=>28,'title'=>'business']
];

echo implode(' -> ',breadcrumber(array_column($resultset,NULL,'id'),31));
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-assign associative keys for easy lookup
```

Output:

```
business -> xxx -> keyword
```

...and here is [another demo using your second set of data](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9020a7738dbfaf4437e443547374dcf3bf49b52e)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function file_list($path)
{
    $result = array();
    $q = "SELECT staticTitle,staticId,parentId FROM tbl_static_pages WHERE staticId = $path";
    $run = mysql_query($q);

    $results = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run))
    {
        if ($row['parentId'] > 1)
        {
            echo $row['staticTitle'];
            $results = array_merge($results, file_list($row['parentId']));
        }
        else
        { 
            $results[] = $result; 
        }
    }  
    return $results;
}
```

Few things that are not clear from your question:

- Breadcrumbs are usually not recursive, so I suppose you do NOT want to actually return a recursive array (array where every element is again array). If you want, follow comment by @midhunjose
- Do you expect the query to ever return multiple records?
- Swap the order of `array_merge` arguments, if you want the parent before child in resulting array.

Comment: @user375947 Formatting is not preserved in comments, please update your question with the database structure.

Comment: See I have a database structure like this.  

staticId ParentId Title

3           1       Media 
19          3       Files
28          19      Network
31          28      Business

and I want breadcrumb like this Business -> Network -> files -> Media

So i want to create a recursive function which runs until partentId reaches to 1 and titles in array.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$result[] = file_list($row['parentId']);
```

instand of

```
$result = file_list($row['parentId']);
```