# Create unlimited unordered list in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create tree from MySQL generated data.

This question has been asked before, but actually it was about creating arrays. So arrays are creating fine. I am using an answer [from this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587341/recursive-function-to-generate-multidimensional-array-from-database-result).

This is the array I am getting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => 1
            [organization_id] => 1
            [parent_organization_id] => 0
            [full_name] => Mohammad Salim Khan
            [employee_order] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [employee_id] => 2
                            [organization_id] => 2
                            [parent_organization_id] => 1
                            [full_name] => Ali Khan
                            [employee_order] => 2
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [employee_id] => 5
                                            [organization_id] => 4
                                            [parent_organization_id] => 2
                                            [full_name] => Nadeem Khan
                                            [employee_order] => 3
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [employee_id] => 7
                                                            [organization_id] => 5
                                                            [parent_organization_id] => 4
                                                            [full_name] => Sajjad Ali
                                                            [employee_order] => 4
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [employee_id] => 3
                            [organization_id] => 3
                            [parent_organization_id] => 1
                            [full_name] => Kamran Durrani
                            [employee_order] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

but I am stuck in putting this data in `<ul>` / `<li>` list.

How can I put this in unordered list so that I get list like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Mohammad Salim Khan</li>
<ul>
//1
<li>Ali Khan</li>
<ul>
<li>Nadeem Khan</li>
<ul><li>Sajjad Ali</li></ul>
//2
<li>Kamran Durrani</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

**Update:**

- Muhammad Salim Khan
- - Ali Khan
- - - Nadeem Khan
- - - - Sajjad Ali
- - Kamran Durrani

It's getting very confusing as there are unlimited possibilities of li's.

Comment: Given an array of n.n.n.n... (eg 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1 etc), what format are you looking for the output to be in?

Comment: @Mike
Sir, i am looking in <ul><li> format, i have given example in end of my question. i tried many ways but none of it is working :(

Comment: In your example, Mohammad is stand-alone while the rest are embedded. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Mike
No, Actually Muhammad Parent ID is 0 `[parent_organization_id] => 0`,
There are no others with parent id 0 thats why its standing alone, but its possible that there can be others with parent id 0.

Comment: @Mike Updated my question add nested list for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a situation for recursion (a function calling itself). Starting with the list in $myLIst:

```
function showList ($myList)
{
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($myList as $row)
    {
        echo ("<li>{$row ['full_name']}</li>\n");
        if  (isset ($row ['children']))
            showList ($row ['children']);
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. I did some changes, but your solution is awesome of recursive function :)