# PHP Multidimensional Parent-Child Array- Certain Elements Being Overwritten

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, jstree

I am having real trouble generating a parent-child tree out of two database tables.

It's meant to reference folders and files inside them.

I am almost there, the code below generates the tree (sourced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587341/recursive-function-to-generate-multidimensional-array-from-database-result)), but any files that are assigned to a category that contains sub-categories- they don't show..

How can I make them show?

**Here is what is currently happening**
[image]

**Here is what I am wanting to happen**
[image]

I believe the issue is with function Generate_Tree_Of_Categories($Tree_Data).

```
function Generate_Tree_Of_Categories(array $elements, $parentId = "NONE")
{
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['child_of'] == $parentId) {
            $children = Generate_Tree_Of_Categories($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;

            }
            $branch[] = $element;
        } else {
          $element = null;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}
```

Here are my DB tables:

```
**Categories table:**
Reference       Title                   Type        Child_Of    Status
CAT202480   Software                    CATEGORY    NONE        ACTIVE
CAT893984   Product Manuals             CATEGORY    NONE        ACTIVE
CAT384594   Manufacturing               CATEGORY    NONE        ACTIVE
CAT394858   Manufacturing Manuals       CATEGORY    CAT384594   ACTIVE
CAT394811   Videos                      CATEGORY    NONE        ACTIVE
CAT111338   Product Videos              CATEGORY    CAT394811   ACTIVE
CAT339844   Commissioning Software      CATEGORY    CAT202480   ACTIVE
CAT339845   Release Versions            CATEGORY    CAT339844   ACTIVE
CAT339846   Beta Versions               CATEGORY    CAT339844   ACTIVE

**Files Table:**
Reference       Type        Title                       Category_Ref    Format  Status
FILE001393804   SOFTWARE    Beta software v0.9.3            CAT339846   ZIP     AVAILABLE
FILE001984843   DOCUMENT    Product A Installation Manual   CAT893984   PDF     AVAILABLE
FILE009039742   DOCUMENT    Product A Commissioning Guide   CAT893984   PDF     AVAILABLE
FILE683579248   DOCUMENT    Product A User Guide            CAT893984   PDF     AVAILABLE
FILE001393805   SOFTWARE    Product A software Release 1.9  CAT339845   ZIP     AVAILABLE
FILE001393803   SOFTWARE    Product Z program               CAT339844   ZIP     AVAILABLE
```

Here is an [SQL dump](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0yKLIrFhCdSbmRiUzRNRm9TRHc)

Here's my code for converting the above data into JSTree compatible arrays, which I later json_encode.

```
function Load_Downloads_TreeView()
{
    require '../../global/session_manager.php';
    require_once '../../permissions/permissions.php';

    // Determine the permissions for the current user
    $User_Permissions = Get_Permissions_SpecificUser($LoggedInUserReference, $LoggedInFlag);


    $Response = Retrieve_All_Download_Categories_SpecificStatus("ACTIVE", $LoggedInFlag);
    // $Response = Retrieve_All_Download_Categories($LoggedInFlag);
    if ($Response['Decision'] == TRUE) {
        $Download_Categories = $Response['Value'];
    } else {
        echo $Response['Notification'];
        exit();
    }


    // $Response          = Retrieve_Specific_Download_Category("CAT339845", $LoggedInFlag);
    // $Specific_Category = $Response['Value'];

    $Tree_Data = array();
    foreach ($Download_Categories as $Current_Category) {


              // This code returns an array of files assigned to the $Current_Category reference
              $Response = Retrieve_Files_In_Download_Category($Current_Category['Reference'], $LoggedInFlag);
              $Files    = $Response['Value'];
              $Child_Nodes = NULL;
              if (count($Files) > 0) {
                 $Child_Nodes = Return_Files($Files);
              }

            //$Child_Nodes would be filled with the array of files (array of arrays).

            // $Child_Nodes = NULL; //Until I figure out how to nest this information in a multidimensional array with categories

            $Response = Generate_Folder_Node($Current_Category['Reference'],$Current_Category['Name'],$Current_Category['Child_Of'], $Child_Nodes);

            $Tree_Data[] = $Response;

    }

    $Generated_Tree = Generate_Tree_Of_Categories($Tree_Data);

    echo json_encode($Generated_Tree);


}



function Generate_Folder_Node($Element_ID,$Element_Name,$Child_Of, $Child_Nodes) {
  if (!defined('id')) define('id', 'id');
  if (!defined('text')) define('text', 'text');
  if (!defined('type')) define('type', 'type');
  if (!defined('child_of')) define('child_of', 'child_of');
  if (!defined('children')) define('children', 'children');
  if (!defined('state')) define('state', 'state');
  if (!defined('opened')) define('opened', 'opened');
  $Node_Open_Array = array(opened=>"false");

  $Generated_Node = array(id=> $Element_ID, text=>$Element_Name, type=>"folder", child_of=>$Child_Of, children=>$Child_Nodes, state=>$Node_Open_Array);

return $Generated_Node;

}



function Return_Files($Child_Array)
{
  $All_Nodes = array();

    foreach ($Child_Array as $Current_Child_Element) {
        $Element_ID   = $Current_Child_Element['Reference'];
        $Element_Name = $Current_Child_Element['Name'];


        if ($Current_Child_Element['Status'] == "AVAILABLE") {
            $DisabledState = "false";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['Status'] == "UNAVAILABLE") {
            $DisabledState = "true";
        }

        if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "PDF") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "ZIP") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-zip-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "JPG" || $Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "PNG") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-picture-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "XLS" || $Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "XLSX") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-excel-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "DOC" || $Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "DOCX") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-word-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "PPT" || $Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "PPTX") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-powerpoint-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "EXE") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-desktop fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "AVI" || $Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "MP4") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-video-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "MP3" || $Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "WAV") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-sound-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "TXT") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-text-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "HEX" || $Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "BIN") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-code-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file fa-lg text-inverse";
        }

      $Generated_Node = Generate_File_Node($Element_ID,$Element_Name,$Icon,$DisabledState);

      if (is_array($Generated_Node) == true) {
        if (!empty($Generated_Node)) {
          array_push($All_Nodes, $Generated_Node);

        }
      }


      // $All_Nodes[] = $Child_Node;
    }

    return $All_Nodes;

}

function Generate_File_Node($Element_ID,$Element_Name,$Icon,$DisabledState) {

if (!defined('id')) define('id', 'id');
if (!defined('text')) define('text', 'text');
if (!defined('type')) define('type', 'type');
if (!defined('icon')) define('icon', 'icon');
if (!defined('state')) define('state', 'state');
if (!defined('opened')) define('opened', 'opened');
$Node_Open_Array = array(opened=>$DisabledState);

$Generated_Node = array(id=> $Element_ID, text=>$Element_Name, type=>"file", icon=>$Icon, state=>$Node_Open_Array);


return $Generated_Node;

}
```

Comment: What are you looking for -- debugging of your code?  With all due respect that is your job.  At very least you ought to have pinpointed which function is the problem and what the input/output is that is not working as you expect.

Comment: The function causing the issue is **Generate_Tree_Of_Categories** Instead of lecturing me, read the question properly. I think the issue is adequately explained. With all due respect that's your job.

Comment: Great, but you should amend your question with the calling values for the function ($elements, $parentid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code.  There is probably a better way.  I actually removed one of your functions and incorporated it into the other function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
        <title>
        </title>
        <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 11.5" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "root", "stackoverflow");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
$sql="SELECT * from Downloads_Categories ORDER BY id";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
$Download_Categories = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$FolderTree = Generate_Tree_Of_Categories($Download_Categories);
usort($FolderTree, function ($item1, $item2) {
    if ($item1['id'] == $item2['id']) return 0;
    return $item1['id'] < $item2['id'] ? -1 : 1;
});

echo "<pre>" . json_encode($FolderTree, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . "</pre>";

mysqli_close($link);

function Generate_Tree_Of_Categories(array $elements, $parentId = "NONE")
{
    global $link;
    $branch = array();
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element["Child_Of"] == $parentId) {
            $sql="SELECT * from Downloads_Files as DF WHERE '" . $element['Reference'] . "' = DF.Child_Of";
            $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
            $Files = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $Child_Nodes = NULL;

            if (count($Files) > 0) {
                 $Child_Nodes = Return_Files($Files); 
            }
            $children = array_merge(Generate_Tree_Of_Categories($elements, $element['Reference']), Return_Files($Files));

            if ($children) {
                $element += ['children' => $children];
            }
            else {
                $element += ['children' => "NONE"];
            }

            $node = Generate_Folder_Node($element["id"],$element["Name"],$element["Child_Of"], $element["children"]);
            $branch[]=$node;
        }   
    }
    return $branch;
}

function Generate_Folder_Node($Element_ID,$Element_Name,$Child_Of, $Child_Nodes) {

    if (!defined('id')) define('id', 'id');
    if (!defined('text')) define('text', 'text');
    if (!defined('type')) define('type', 'type');
    if (!defined('Child_Of')) define('Child_Of', 'Child_Of');
    if (!defined('children')) define('children', 'children');
    if (!defined('state')) define('state', 'state');
    if (!defined('opened')) define('opened', 'opened');
    $Node_Open_Array = array(opened=>"false");
    $Generated_Node = array(id=> $Element_ID, text=>$Element_Name, type=>"folder", Child_Of=>$Child_Of, children=>$Child_Nodes, state=>$Node_Open_Array);
    return $Generated_Node;
}



function Return_Files($Child_Array) {

    $All_Nodes = array();

    foreach ($Child_Array as $Current_Child_Element) {
        $Element_ID   = $Current_Child_Element['Reference'];
        $Element_Name = $Current_Child_Element['Name'];

        if ($Current_Child_Element['Status'] == "AVAILABLE") {
            $DisabledState = "false";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['Status'] == "UNAVAILABLE") {
            $DisabledState = "true";
        }

        if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "PDF") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "ZIP") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-zip-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "JPG" || $Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "PNG") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-picture-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "XLS" || $Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "XLSX") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-excel-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "DOC" || $Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "DOCX") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-word-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "PPT" || $Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "PPTX") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-powerpoint-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "EXE") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-desktop fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "AVI" || $Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "MP4") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-video-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "MP3" || $Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "WAV") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-sound-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "TXT") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-text-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else if ($Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "HEX" || $Current_Child_Element['File_Type'] == "BIN") {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file-code-o fa-lg text-inverse";
        } else {
            $Icon = "fa fa-file fa-lg text-inverse";
        }

      $Generated_Node = Generate_File_Node($Element_ID,$Element_Name,$Icon,$DisabledState);

      if (is_array($Generated_Node) == true) {
        if (!empty($Generated_Node)) {
          array_push($All_Nodes, $Generated_Node);
        }
      }
    }
    return $All_Nodes;
}

function Generate_File_Node($Element_ID,$Element_Name,$Icon,$DisabledState) {

    if (!defined('id')) define('id', 'id');
    if (!defined('text')) define('text', 'text');
    if (!defined('type')) define('type', 'type');
    if (!defined('icon')) define('icon', 'icon');
    if (!defined('state')) define('state', 'state');
    if (!defined('opened')) define('opened', 'opened');
    $Node_Open_Array = array(opened=>$DisabledState);

    $Generated_Node = array(id=> $Element_ID, text=>$Element_Name, type=>"file", icon=>$Icon, state=>$Node_Open_Array);

    return $Generated_Node;
}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code works perfectly and achieves exactly what I want! You've helped me so much and I am very grateful! I'm just going to change over the mySQLi to PDO

Comment: Do you have the code that you are using to generate the visual for the directory structure (i.e. converting the JSON to HTML for display).  I might find the whole thing useful myself at some point.

Comment: I will have to put it as an "answer" in this thread as the code is too long for a comment

Answer (score 0):

It may be as simple as the Category_Ref for the Product Z program.  You have it has CAT339844.  Shouldn't it be CAT339846 ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! It would be fine if it was CAT339846, but I want files in the same level as CAT339846 and CAT339845 (so FILE001393803 should be showing at the same level as Beta Software and Release Software)

Comment: To make debugging easier for us it would be nice to have code to actually test, including an .sql for the database.  As an aside, there is a jQuery script that does something quite similar which you could modify to given what you want.  Check out:  [link]https://www.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-file-tree#demo.  It has connectors for you database as well.

Comment: Apologies for not adding that before, totally forgot. Here is the  [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0yKLIrFhCdSbmRiUzRNRm9TRHc) to my sql file... Going to take a look at that link you provided!

Comment: There is a demo on that page.  I've used it before and it probably would work.  You might have to disable the animation if you don't want that.

Comment: Thank you for referencing that, I just don't think I like how it looks.. The web portal I have built includes a custom theme for JSTree, which is why I would like to stick with it- plus I feel like I am almost done with getting it working. It's just the issue with files inside folders which already contain sub-folders not showing

Comment: I might look at your code then.  Did notice that in function Generate_Tree_Of_Categories(array $elements, $parentId = "NULL), you have "NULL, which might be a problem.

Comment: that's a typo due to working on the same thing for days on end! It should read $parentId = "NONE". Will correct the original.

Comment: i've just noticed, that the code doesn't add files at the base level, if they have been assigned "NONE" as a child. Works fine for folders, but not files

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but I rewrote it so that it gives this JSON output.  How are you translating that into a visual display of the structure.  I don't see the code for that.

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "text": "Software",
        "type": "folder",
        "Child_Of": "NONE",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "7",
                "text": "Commissioning Software",
                "type": "folder",
                "Child_Of": "CAT202480",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "8",
                        "text": "Release Versions",
                        "type": "folder",
                        "Child_Of": "CAT339844",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": "FILE001393805",
                                "text": "Product A software Release 1.9",
                                "type": "file",
                                "icon": "fa fa-file-zip-o fa-lg text-inverse",
                                "state": {
                                    "opened": "false"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "state": {
                            "opened": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "9",
                        "text": "Beta Versions",
                        "type": "folder",
                        "Child_Of": "CAT339844",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": "FILE001393804",
                                "text": "Beta software v0.9.3",
                                "type": "file",
                                "icon": "fa fa-file-zip-o fa-lg text-inverse",
                                "state": {
                                    "opened": "false"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "state": {
                            "opened": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "FILE001393803",
                        "text": "Product Z program",
                        "type": "file",
                        "icon": "fa fa-file-zip-o fa-lg text-inverse",
                        "state": {
                            "opened": "false"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "state": {
                    "opened": "false"
                }
            }
        ],
        "state": {
            "opened": "false"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "text": "Product Manuals",
        "type": "folder",
        "Child_Of": "NONE",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "FILE001984843",
                "text": "Product A Installation Manual",
                "type": "file",
                "icon": "fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-lg text-inverse",
                "state": {
                    "opened": "false"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "FILE009039742",
                "text": "Product A Commissioning Guide",
                "type": "file",
                "icon": "fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-lg text-inverse",
                "state": {
                    "opened": "false"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "FILE683579248",
                "text": "Product A User Guide",
                "type": "file",
                "icon": "fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-lg text-inverse",
                "state": {
                    "opened": "false"
                }
            }
        ],
        "state": {
            "opened": "false"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "text": "Manufacturing",
        "type": "folder",
        "Child_Of": "NONE",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "4",
                "text": "Manufacturing Manuals",
                "type": "folder",
                "Child_Of": "CAT384594",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "FILE2000000001",
                        "text": "Product A Manufacturing Manual",
                        "type": "file",
                        "icon": "fa fa-file-word-o fa-lg text-inverse",
                        "state": {
                            "opened": "false"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "state": {
                    "opened": "false"
                }
            }
        ],
        "state": {
            "opened": "false"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "text": "Videos",
        "type": "folder",
        "Child_Of": "NONE",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "6",
                "text": "Product Videos",
                "type": "folder",
                "Child_Of": "CAT394811",
                "children": "NONE",
                "state": {
                    "opened": "false"
                }
            }
        ],
        "state": {
            "opened": "false"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wishing to use this solution, below is a link to the JStree initialisation instructions and below that is my code that I use to populate the tree:

**Initialisation:** 
https://www.jstree.com/docs/config/

Note- be sure to check out the plugins and modify the initialisation code to include those. Thankfully the website template I purchased came with a custom theme for JSTree and all the relevant plugins.

```
function Generate_Downloads_TreeView() {
    var FunctionToRun = "Request_Download_Tree";
  var http = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "controller.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      FunctionToRun: FunctionToRun
    }

  });
  http.done(function(data, textStatus, jQxhr) {

        $('#jstree-default').jstree({
        "core": {
                    'data': data,


        },
        "types": {
            "default": { "icon": "fa fa-folder text-warning fa-lg" },
            "file": { "icon": "fa fa-file text-warning fa-lg" }
        },
        "plugins": [ "dnd", "state", "types" ]
    });

  });
```

Here is the tree working:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFbwH.png)

Thank you once again to @sscotti !