# PHP - Add level to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array and I want to add a key and value to every array within the multidimensional array. The value has to be the level of how deep the array is within the multidimensional array.

For example:

```
Array(
    [0] Array
        (
            [id] 1
            [parentid] null
            [0] Array
                (
                    [id] 101
                    [parentid] 1
    [1] Array
        (
            [id] 2
            [parentid] null
            [0] Array
                (
                    [id] 161
                    [parentid] 2
                    [children] Array
                        (
                            [0] Array
                                (
                                    [id] 300
                                    [parentid] 161
                                 )
```

Expected output:

```
Array(
    [0] Array
        (
            [id] 1
            [parentid] null
            [level] 1
            [0] Array
                (
                    [id] 101
                    [parentid] 1
                    [level] 2
    [1] Array
        (
            [id] 2
            [parentid] null
            [level] 1
            [0] Array
                (
                    [id] 161
                    [parentid] 2
                    [level] 2
                    [children] Array
                        (
                            [0] Array
                                (
                                    [id] 300
                                    [parentid] 161
                                    [level] 3
                                 )
```

Comment: What have you tried to get this done? It should not be that difficult

Comment: You can check there :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587341/recursive-function-to-generate-multidimensional-array-from-database-result/8587437#8587437

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to use a recursive function that works with a [*reference*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) to an array.

By using a parameter `&$foo` with the `&` in front of it, you're designating it as a reference to that object.

In the case of an array it will not make a copy of the modification, but perform the modification on the original passed array.

**EDIT** added suggestion of [Yoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697154/yoshi)  in the comments to pass `&value`  as reference too.

See it live: https://ideone.com/NhKABF

```
<?php
$array = [
    'hello' => 'world',
    'doing' => [
        'hello' => 'universe',
        'going' => [
            'hello' => 'existence'
         ],
        'moving' => [
            'answer' => 42,
        ]
    ]
];
function levelUp(&$array, $level = 1) 
//               ^-- See that one? that's the  magic.
{
    $array['level'] = $level;

    foreach($array as $key => &$value) {
    //                        ^-- important to add that & here too
        if(is_array($value)) {
            levelUp($value, $level + 1);
        }
    }
}
levelUp($array);
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Small thing: I think the OP wants the `level` field set to the data's nesting level, not the `id` field. Otherwise great answer.

Comment: @Nibboro is given solution solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
$branch = array();

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
        $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
        if ($children) {
            $element['children'] = $children;
        }
        $branch[] = $element;
    }
}

return $branch;
```

}

```
$tree = buildTree($rows);
```

Comment: I think it will help you.

Comment: Obviously, because otherwise you wouldn't have posted it ;)

Comment: I use this function to build my tree structure. But I've no idea how to add the current level of the array to the array.

Comment: Have you store level in DB??

Comment: No, the level is not stored in the database yet. Im trying to add the level in the array and want to use that array to insert the data in the database.

Comment: Can you please post your database table structure so that we can give you best answer.

Comment: I am using same array but i store level of that node and get array from DB and then make child parent relationship.

Comment: The content of the array in the example, is build from data that comes from multiple database tables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's relevant but why not use a library like [BlueM/Tree](https://github.com/BlueM/Tree) ? 
It has features built for this kind of problems.

```
// Get a node's ID
$id = $node->getId();

// Get the node's hierarchical level (1-based)
$level = $node->getLevel();
```

Comment: May be but i have not use yet that library.