# How to build tree (id, parent_id) in css based on flat array in php

Tags: php, html, css

I want to display my query results in a tree form in HTML and CSS.
After some searching the internet, I came across a very good library:
https://dumptyd.github.io/treeflex/

I got this data using CTE in My database.
Here is the data:

```
WITH RECURSIVE category_path (id, parent_id, lvl, name, path) AS
                   (
                       SELECT id, parent_id ,0 lvl, name, name as path
                       FROM account_roll_up
                       WHERE parent_id IS NULL
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT c.id, c.parent_id,  (cp.lvl + 1), c.name, CONCAT(cp.path, ' > ', c.name)
                       FROM category_path AS cp JOIN account_roll_up AS c
                                                     ON cp.id = c.parent_id
                   )
SELECT  id,parent_id, lvl, name AS name FROM category_path
ORDER BY path;



+------+-----------+------+--------------------------------------+
| id   | parent_id | lvl  | name                                 |
+------+-----------+------+--------------------------------------+
|   23 |      NULL |    0 | Laporan Keuangan                     |
|   25 |        23 |    1 | Laporan Laba Rugi                    |
|   12 |        25 |    2 | Laba (Rugi) Sebelum Pajak            |
|   16 |        12 |    3 | Laba (Rugi) Usaha                    |
|   13 |        16 |    4 | Laba (Rugi) Kotor                    |
|   15 |        13 |    5 | Total Biaya Langsung                 |
|   14 |        13 |    5 | Total Jumlah Pendapatan              |
|   17 |        16 |    4 | Total Biaya Administrasi & Umum      |
|   18 |        17 |    5 | Total Biaya Administrasi             |
|   19 |        17 |    5 | Total Biaya Umum                     |
|   20 |        12 |    3 | Total Pendapatan & Biaya Lain - Lain |
|   22 |        20 |    4 | Total Biaya Lain-Lain                |
|   21 |        20 |    4 | Total Pendapatan Lain - Lain         |
|   24 |        23 |    1 | Laporan Neraca                       |
|    1 |        24 |    2 | Total Aktiva                         |
|    6 |         1 |    3 | Total Aktiva Lainnya                 |
|    2 |         1 |    3 | Total Aktiva Lancar                  |
|    4 |         1 |    3 | Total Aktiva Tetap                   |
|    5 |         1 |    3 | Total Aktiva Tidak Berwujud          |
|    3 |         1 |    3 | Total Investasi Jangka Panjang       |
|    7 |        24 |    2 | Total Hutang & Modal                 |
|    8 |         7 |    3 | Total Hutang                         |
|   10 |         8 |    4 | Total Hutang Jangka Panjang          |
|    9 |         8 |    4 | Total Hutang Jangka Pendek           |
|   11 |         7 |    3 | Total Modal                          |
+------+-----------+------+--------------------------------------+
25 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

As an array in php :

```
[
    0 => [
        'id' => '23'
        'lvl' => '0'
        'name' => 'Laporan Keuangan'
    ]
    1 => [
        'id' => '25'
        'lvl' => '1'
        'name' => 'Laporan Laba Rugi'
    ]
    2 => [
        'id' => '12'
        'lvl' => '2'
        'name' => 'Laba (Rugi) Sebelum Pajak'
    ] ....
    to 25,
```

How to build this flat array into those treeflex?
Any help it so appreciated.

So, I change my mind to restructure those array by copy the original one.

Now, the problem, how to generate this tree into treeflex,

```
[
    0 => [
        'id' => '23'
        'parent_id' => null
        'lvl' => '0'
        'name' => 'Laporan Keuangan'
        'children' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => '25'
                'parent_id' => '23'
                'lvl' => '1'
                'name' => 'Laporan Laba Rugi'
                'children' => [
                    0 => [
                        'id' => '12'
                        'parent_id' => '25'
                        'lvl' => '2'
                        'name' => 'Laba (Rugi) Sebelum Pajak'
                        'children' => [
                            0 => [
                                'id' => '16'
                                'parent_id' => '12'
                                'lvl' => '3'
                                'name' => 'Laba (Rugi) Usaha'
                                'children' => [
                                    0 => [
                                        'id' => '13'
                                        'parent_id' => '16'
                                        'lvl' => '4'
                                        'name' => 'Laba (Rugi) Kotor'
                                        'children' => [...]
                                    ]
                                    1 => [
                                        'id' => '17'
                                        'parent_id' => '16'
                                        'lvl' => '4'
                                        'name' => 'Total Biaya Administrasi & Umum'
                                        'children' => [...]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                            1 => [
                                'id' => '20'
                                'parent_id' => '12'
                                'lvl' => '3'
                                'name' => 'Total Pendapatan & Biaya Lain - Lain'
                                'children' => [
                                    0 => [
                                        'id' => '22'
                                        'parent_id' => '20'
                                        'lvl' => '4'
                                        'name' => 'Total Biaya Lain-Lain'
                                    ]
                                    1 => [
                                        'id' => '21'
                                        'parent_id' => '20'
                                        'lvl' => '4'
                                        'name' => 'Total Pendapatan Lain - Lain'
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            1 => [
                'id' => '24'
                'parent_id' => '23'
                'lvl' => '1'
                'name' => 'Laporan Neraca'
                'children' => [
                    0 => [
                        'id' => '1'
                        'parent_id' => '24'
                        'lvl' => '2'
                        'name' => 'Total Aktiva'
                        'children' => [
                            0 => [
                                'id' => '6'
                                'parent_id' => '1'
                                'lvl' => '3'
                                'name' => 'Total Aktiva Lainnya'
                            ]
                            1 => [
                                'id' => '2'
                                'parent_id' => '1'
                                'lvl' => '3'
                                'name' => 'Total Aktiva Lancar'
                            ]
                            2 => [
                                'id' => '4'
                                'parent_id' => '1'
                                'lvl' => '3'
                                'name' => 'Total Aktiva Tetap'
                            ]
                            3 => [
                                'id' => '5'
                                'parent_id' => '1'
                                'lvl' => '3'
                                'name' => 'Total Aktiva Tidak Berwujud'
                            ]
                            4 => [
                                'id' => '3'
                                'parent_id' => '1'
                                'lvl' => '3'
                                'name' => 'Total Investasi Jangka Panjang'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                    1 => [
                        'id' => '7'
                        'parent_id' => '24'
                        'lvl' => '2'
                        'name' => 'Total Hutang & Modal'
                        'children' => [
                            0 => [
                                'id' => '8'
                                'parent_id' => '7'
                                'lvl' => '3'
                                'name' => 'Total Hutang'
                                'children' => [
                                    0 => [
                                        'id' => '10'
                                        'parent_id' => '8'
                                        'lvl' => '4'
                                        'name' => 'Total Hutang Jangka Panjang'
                                    ]
                                    1 => [
                                        'id' => '9'
                                        'parent_id' => '8'
                                        'lvl' => '4'
                                        'name' => 'Total Hutang Jangka Pendek'
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                            1 => [
                                'id' => '11'
                                'parent_id' => '7'
                                'lvl' => '3'
                                'name' => 'Total Modal'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: What have you attempted to solve this? It seems like nothing more than restructuring your array. If you've tried to write some code, please share it and explain where it fails to produce what you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive function to generate multidimensional array from database result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587341/recursive-function-to-generate-multidimensional-array-from-database-result)

Comment: I use Yii2 framework to develop this app, so, to avoid framework based, I just post the general problem.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal No, I dont want to restructured those array

Comment: Why would you not want to do the exact thing that makes this possible? If you need the array in its original form for something else, make a copy and restructure that.

Comment: @FadlyDzil I think you do. Having a recursive array would make it easy to build this. How else do you expect to echo this in the correct order? When do you create a new ul, how do you know when you need a ul inside a ul?

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal that's the real problem. It so hard to know when we need ul inside a li,

Comment: _“As an array in php :”_ - so where exactly does this contain the information now, which element is a child of which one (or vice versa)? You only have the `lvl` in there, but `parent_id` isn’t even contained in this data.

Comment: @FadlyDzil *"It so hard to know when we need ul inside a li"*, is it? In the recursive array you would check <array has index 'children'> or <array has not index 'children'>. <array has not index 'children'> => show name; <array has index 'children'> => create new ul and loop through this array.

Comment: @CBroe Please see my update question

Answer (score 0):

This is based my project.

```
 public static function buildTreeOutAsHtml($tree) {
        $markup = "";
        foreach ($tree as $branch => $twig) {
            if (isset($twig['children'])) {
                $markup .=
                    '<li>' .
                    \yii\helpers\Html::tag('span', $twig['name'], [
                        'class' => 'tf-nc'
                    ]) . self::buildTreeOutAsHtml($twig['children']) .
                    '</li>';
            } else {
                $markup .= '<li>' .
                    \yii\helpers\Html::tag('span', $twig['name'], [
                        'class' => 'tf-nc'
                    ]) . '</li>';
            }
        }
        return "<ul>" . $markup . "</ul>";
    }
```