# php function that create nested ul li from array+object

Tags: php, arrays, nested-loops

i have array+object like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 1
            [parent_id] => 0
            [language] => th
            [t_type] => category
            [t_name] => cat1
            [t_description] => 
            [t_uri] => cat1
            [t_uri_encoded] => cat1
            [t_uris] => 
            [meta_title] => 
            [meta_description] => 
            [meta_keywords] => 
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [tid] => 3
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [language] => th
                            [t_type] => category
                            [t_name] => cat1.1
                            [t_description] => 
                            [t_uri] => cat1.1
                            [t_uri_encoded] => cat1.1
                            [t_uris] => 
                            [meta_title] => 
                            [meta_description] => 
                            [meta_keywords] => 
                            [childs] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [tid] => 5
                                            [parent_id] => 3
                                            [language] => th
                                            [t_type] => category
                                            [t_name] => cat1.1.1
                                            [t_description] => 
                                            [t_uri] => cat1.1.1
                                            [t_uri_encoded] => cat1.1.1
                                            [t_uris] => 
                                            [meta_title] => 
                                            [meta_description] => 
                                            [meta_keywords] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [tid] => 4
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [language] => th
                            [t_type] => category
                            [t_name] => cat1.2
                            [t_description] => 
                            [t_uri] => cat1.2
                            [t_uri_encoded] => cat1.2
                            [t_uris] => 
                            [meta_title] => 
                            [meta_description] => 
                            [meta_keywords] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 2
            [parent_id] => 0
            [language] => th
            [t_type] => category
            [t_name] => cat2
            [t_description] => 
            [t_uri] => cat2
            [t_uri_encoded] => cat2
            [t_uris] => 
            [meta_title] => 
            [meta_description] => 
            [meta_keywords] => 
        )

)
```

this array+object in json string

```
[{"tid":"1","parent_id":"0","language":"th","t_type":"category","t_name":"cat1","t_description":null,"t_uri":"cat1","t_uri_encoded":"cat1","t_uris":null,"meta_title":null,"meta_description":null,"meta_keywords":null,"childs":[{"tid":"3","parent_id":"1","language":"th","t_type":"category","t_name":"cat1.1","t_description":null,"t_uri":"cat1.1","t_uri_encoded":"cat1.1","t_uris":null,"meta_title":null,"meta_description":null,"meta_keywords":null,"childs":[{"tid":"5","parent_id":"3","language":"th","t_type":"category","t_name":"cat1.1.1","t_description":null,"t_uri":"cat1.1.1","t_uri_encoded":"cat1.1.1","t_uris":null,"meta_title":null,"meta_description":null,"meta_keywords":null}]},{"tid":"4","parent_id":"1","language":"th","t_type":"category","t_name":"cat1.2","t_description":null,"t_uri":"cat1.2","t_uri_encoded":"cat1.2","t_uris":null,"meta_title":null,"meta_description":null,"meta_keywords":null}]},{"tid":"2","parent_id":"0","language":"th","t_type":"category","t_name":"cat2","t_description":null,"t_uri":"cat2","t_uri_encoded":"cat2","t_uris":null,"meta_title":null,"meta_description":null,"meta_keywords":null}]
```

**how to create nested ul li like this.**

```
<ul>
  <li>cat1
    <ul>
        <li>cat1.1
            <ul>
                <li>cat1.1.1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>cat1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>cat2</li>
</ul>
```

this is what i have tried

```
echo list_nested_cat( $list_item );
function list_nested_cat( $list_item, $start = 0) {
    echo '<ul style="margin-left: 1em;">';
    foreach ( $list_item as $item ) {
        if ( isset( $item->childs ) && is_array( $item->childs ) ) {
            echo '<li>'.$item->t_name.'</li>';
            list_nested_cat($item->childs);
        } else {
            echo '<li>'.$item->t_name.'</li>';
        }

    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

but this function echo incorrect html nested ul li format.

ps. i create array object from the code of arnaud576875

[PHP tree structure for categories and sub categories without looping a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843945/php-tree-structure-for-categories-and-sub-categories-without-looping-a-query)

Comment: Please post that ugly array as a JSON string for testing purposes?

Comment: @iambriansreed i posted JSON string as you request.

Comment: @vee I used it to test my code and fixed some errors. See the updated code posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started:

It uses a recursive function; it calls itself.

**UPDATED**

Tested with the JSON object and fixed some errors

```
<?php    

echo make_ulli($object); 

function make_ulli($array){
    if(!is_array($array)) return '';

    $output = '<ul>';
    foreach($array as $item){  

        $output .= '<li>' . $item->t_name;      

        if(property_exists($item, 'childs'))
            $output .= make_ulli($item->childs);

        $output .= '</li>';

    }   
    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;
}


?>
```