# How to pull children array (with object) to parent if exceed max depth?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, tree

### Data

I have a data like this.

```php
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 1
            [t_name] => A
            [t_level] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [tid] => 5
                            [t_name] => A.1
                            [t_level] => 2
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [tid] => 6
                            [t_name] => A.2
                            [t_level] => 2
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [tid] => 7
                                            [t_name] => A.2.1
                                            [t_level] => 3
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [tid] => 9
                                                            [t_name] => A.2.1.1
                                                            [t_level] => 4
                                                            [array_val] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => 0
                                                                    [1] => 1
                                                                    [2] => 2
                                                                )

                                                            [obj_val] => stdClass Object
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [tid] => 10
                                                            [t_name] => A.2.1.2
                                                            [t_level] => 4
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [tid] => 8
                                            [t_name] => A.2.2
                                            [t_level] => 3
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 2
            [t_name] => B
            [t_level] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 3
            [t_name] => C
            [t_level] => 1
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 4
            [t_name] => D
            [t_level] => 1
        )

)
```

Original data converted to JSON:

```json
[{"tid":1,"t_name":"A","t_level":1,"children":[{"tid":5,"t_name":"A.1","t_level":2},{"tid":6,"t_name":"A.2","t_level":2,"children":[{"tid":7,"t_name":"A.2.1","t_level":3,"children":[{"tid":9,"t_name":"A.2.1.1","t_level":4,"array_val":[0,1,2],"obj_val":{}},{"tid":10,"t_name":"A.2.1.2","t_level":4}]},{"tid":8,"t_name":"A.2.2","t_level":3}]}]},{"tid":2,"t_name":"B","t_level":1},{"tid":3,"t_name":"C","t_level":1},{"tid":4,"t_name":"D","t_level":1}]
```

It's 4 level depth, I would like to pull all children that is deeper than 2 to their parent list at level 2.

#### Expected result

```php
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 1
            [t_name] => A
            [t_level] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [tid] => 5
                            [t_name] => A.1
                            [t_level] => 2
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [tid] => 6
                            [t_name] => A.2
                            [t_level] => 2
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [tid] => 7
                            [t_name] => A.2.1
                            [t_level] => 2
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [tid] => 9
                            [t_name] => A.2.1.1
                            [t_level] => 2
                            [array_val] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 0
                                    [1] => 1
                                    [2] => 2
                                )

                            [obj_val] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [tid] => 10
                            [t_name] => A.2.1.2
                            [t_level] => 2
                        )

                    [5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [tid] => 8
                            [t_name] => A.2.2
                            [t_level] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 2
            [t_name] => B
            [t_level] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 3
            [t_name] => C
            [t_level] => 1
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 4
            [t_name] => D
            [t_level] => 1
        )

)
```

Expected result in JSON:

```json
[{"tid":1,"t_name":"A","t_level":1,"children":[{"tid":5,"t_name":"A.1","t_level":2},{"tid":6,"t_name":"A.2","t_level":2},{"tid":7,"t_name":"A.2.1","t_level":2},{"tid":9,"t_name":"A.2.1.1","t_level":2,"array_val":[0,1,2],"obj_val":{}},{"tid":10,"t_name":"A.2.1.2","t_level":2},{"tid":8,"t_name":"A.2.2","t_level":2}]},{"tid":2,"t_name":"B","t_level":1},{"tid":3,"t_name":"C","t_level":1},{"tid":4,"t_name":"D","t_level":1}]
```

### Code

This is what I tried but I have no idea how to move them to parent. It seems there is no function/method to set parent value or append to parent's list.

```php
$maxDepth = 2;// max depth allowed.
$RAI = new \RecursiveArrayIterator($array);
$RII = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($RAI, \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$RII->setMaxDepth($maxDepth);
foreach ($RII as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === 't_level' && intval($value) > $maxDepth) {
        // what to do? can't move them to their parent.
    }
}// endforeach;
unset($key, $value);
$array = $RII->getArrayCopy();

// see result.
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Curious to know why you need to do this?

Comment: @Olivier It's for rebuild the data structure of menu items, categories tree, something like this before display it on the page. ([this is function for built HTML in case anyone looking for it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10309121/128761)).

Comment: More example: You may have very deep category tree but Bootstrap supported only 2 levels deep of navbar menu. So, you may rebuild that array without cut/lose anything and use that array to built Bootstrap navbar menu.

Comment: at the time when you create the structure at that time create structure as per need and if you are getting it by api then do one thing create recursive function
in that do as usuals till 2 depth after that use recursive function to fetch until you reach last level then put it into your desire depth  
in that way
check variable type is array then call recursive function else you are at lowest depth 
use while operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a recursive function that performs a depth-first traversal, and which relies on the `$depth` argument to choose whether to use the recursive result array to extend a flattened array, or to keep the nested structure.

Code:

```
function flattenAtDepth($array, $depth) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $obj) {
        $rest = [];
        if (isset($obj->children)) {
            $obj = clone $obj;
            $children = flattenAtDepth($obj->children, $depth-1);
            if ($depth <= 1) {
                unset($obj->children);
                $rest = $children;
            } else {
                $obj->children = $children;
>t_level + 1; 
            }
        }
        array_push($result, $obj, ...$rest);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Call as:

```
$result = flattenAtDepth($array, $maxDepth);
```

I would not update the `t_level` properties as they constitute redundant information. I would actually leave those properties out.

Comment: Upvoted. This is good answer that work but almost 100%. The thing left is `t_level` isn't change. This code looks good and working good. Thank you.

Comment: Add `$maxDepth` as thrid argument and add `if ($depth <= 1) {$obj->t_level = $maxDepth;}`  at the beginning of `foreach`  is working.

Comment: I see. I have added a line that sets the `t_level` properties. This way the extra parameter is not needed. But your way to do it is nice as well.

Comment: But honestly, the depth property is redundant information, as this is already clear from the structure. I would kick it out.

Comment: With current edit, the `foreach... t_level+1` will be wrong if max depth is 1. It's OK to keep 3rd argument.

Comment: Yes, that is the downside. It only affects `children` arrays. It will not do anything to objects that end up outside them -- at the top level. But again, maintaining redundant information is not really what I would go for. To be consistent with that viewpoint I have reverted that edit and added a phrase about that.