# Building a tree of categories: server or client?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, architecture, tree

In my web app I need to render a category tree, stored in a MySQL database. The data is fetched by the app using AJAX. I can build the [tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843945/php-tree-structure-for-categories-and-sub-categories-without-looping-a-query) either on the server or a client. I wonder where to put this logic. Should the server return the prepared tree, or just plain database rows? I'm using backbone.js in the client code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that client-side by overloading the `Backbone.Model.parse()` to add the desired functionality.

Comment: I had the same idea, just using `Backbone.Collection.parse()` :)

Comment: glad it helped. Consider accepting the answer if you are done.